# Writing data in hive warehouse directory in two separate tables using flume

Tags: apache, hadoop, bigdata, flume, flume-ng

I want to write data in hive warehouse directory, in two separate tables called `flumemaleemployee` and `flumefemaleemployee`. Last `3 records` should be inserted in the `female` table and upper `3 records` should be inserted in `male` table.Below is my data:

```
1,alok,mumbai
1,jatin,chennai
1,yogesh,kolkata
2,ragini,delhi
2,jyotsana,pune
1,valmiki,banglore
```

Below is my `flume` `conf` code:

```
agent.sources = tailsrc 
agent.channels = mem1 mem2 
agent.sinks = stdl std2 
agent.sources.tailsrc.type = exec 
agent.sources.tailsrc.command = tail -F /home/cloudera/Desktop/in.txt 
agent.sources.tailsrc.batchSize = 1 
agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors = i1 
agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.type = regex_extractor 
agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.il.regex = A(\\d} 
agent.sources.tailsrc. interceptors. M.serializers = t1 
agent.sources.tailsrc. interceptors, i1.serializers.t1. name = type 
agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.type = multiplexing 
agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.header = type 
agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.mapping.1 = mem1 
agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.mapping.2 = mem2 
agent.sinks.std1.type = hdfs 
agent.sinks.stdl.channel = mem1 
agent.sinks.stdl.batchSize = 1 
agent.sinks.std1.hdfs.path = /user/hive/warehouse/aisehibanayatp.db/flumemaleemployee
agent.sinks.stdl.rolllnterval = 0 
agent.sinks.stdl.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
agent.sinks.std2.type = hdfs 
agent.sinks.std2.channel = mem2 
agent.sinks.std2.batchSize = 1 
agent.sinks.std2.hdfs.path = /user/hi ve/warehouse/aisehibanayatp.db/flumefemaleemployee
agent.sinks.std2.rolllnterval = 0 
agent.sinks.std2.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
agent.channels.mem1.type = memory 
agent.channels.meml.capacity = 100 
agent.channels.mem2.type = memory 
agent.channels.mem2.capacity = 100 
agent.sources.tailsrc.channels = mem1 mem2
```

I am not getting any error but when I start `flume` `service` with below command it just stucks at something I don't know how to deal with that since I am not getting any error

```
flume-ng agent --name agent -conf-file /home/cloudera/Desktop/flume1.config
```

and it stucks at below step:

```
18/11/13 08:03:00 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: mem2. channel.event.take.success == 0
18/11/13 08:03:00 INFO node.Application: Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{std2=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@17ade71c counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{mem2=org.apache.flume.channel.MemoryChannel{name: mem2}} }
18/11/13 08:03:00 INFO node.Application: Starting Channel mem2
18/11/13 08:03:00 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: CHANNEL, name: mem2 started
18/11/13 08:03:00 INFO node.Application: Starting Sink std2
18/11/13 08:03:00 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SINK, name: std2: Successfully registered new MBean.
18/11/13 08:03:00 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: std2 started
```

So how can I achieve this ??

Comment: Not sure I understand the regex. Should it not be based on value of first col, 1 or 2?

Comment: looks ok at first glance

Comment: yeah it doesn't throw any error

Comment: my first comment? can you find output files?

Comment: I do not think there is an error

Comment: No, there were no files

Comment: Can you modify according to your knowledge my flume config file in order to get my problem solved. Coz I tried my best but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183583/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-rushhour).

Comment: regex issue and type and white spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is typos and lack of formatting and spaces and l instead of 1. I managed to fix these and it ran, I altered your regex, you can tailor that, but most of it is an accuracy issue. Use the file as follows and it works, your own HDFS and settings of course:

```
agent.sources = tailsrc 
agent.channels = mem1 mem2 
agent.sinks = std1 std2 
agent.sources.tailsrc.type = exec 
agent.sources.tailsrc.command = tail -F /home/cloudera/in.txt 
agent.sources.tailsrc.batchSize = 1 
agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors = i1 
agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.type = regex_extractor 
agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.regex = ^.*(1|2) 
agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.serializers = t1 
agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.serializers.t1.name = type 
agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.type = multiplexing 
agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.header = type 
agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.mapping.1 = mem1 
agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.mapping.2 = mem2
agent.sinks.std1.type = hdfs 
agent.sinks.std1.channel = mem1 
agent.sinks.std1.batchSize = 1 
agent.sinks.std1.hdfs.path = hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/flumemaleemployee
agent.sinks.std1.rolllnterval = 0 
agent.sinks.std1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
agent.sinks.std2.type = hdfs 
agent.sinks.std2.channel = mem2 
agent.sinks.std2.batchSize = 1 
agent.sinks.std2.hdfs.path =  hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/flumefemaleemployee
agent.sinks.std2.rolllnterval = 0 
agent.sinks.std2.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
agent.channels.mem1.type = memory 
agent.channels.meml.capacity = 100 
agent.channels.mem2.type = memory 
agent.channels.mem2.capacity = 100 
agent.sources.tailsrc.channels = mem1 mem2
```

Comment: If I follow documentation and If I use only mandatory properties for source. Like for "exec" the only mandatory property is type and command. So will it work with these two properties also ?? Coz I haven't understood the purpose of other properties over here

Comment: Yeah it worked but it would be very helpful if you can explain me those properties in layman terms specially the regex part so that in future I can tackle such problems

Comment: It ran and for me it’s over. Work to do

Comment: Okay whenever you get time will you help me with understanding these properties ?

Comment: Ok will do but the example is reading from a file that gets the stuff and  from start of line looks for 1 or 2 ans splits to 2 files. I will post you a link to read on regex

Comment: can i get the link ??

Comment: This https://dzone.com/articles/apache-flume-regex-filtering and this https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#regex-extractor-interceptor

Comment: Thanks. I ll refer it and will let u know

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54426075/spark-submit-throws-an-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-scala-runtime-jav