# spark submit throws an error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.java8.JFunction2$mcIII$sp

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I wrote a code for word count but when I tried running it from CMD in windows using below command it throws an exception.

```
spark-submit --class com.sample.WordCount --master local file:///E:/WordCountSample/target/WordCountSample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar file:///C:/Users/siddh/OneDrive/Desktop/sample.txt
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SparkSampleInScala</groupId>
    <artifactId>WordCountSample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>WordCountSample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!--<build> <plugins> <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> <version>3.0.0-M1</version> 
        </plugin> </plugins> </build> -->
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.8</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

but when I ran spark submit it throws below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/java8/JFunction2$mcIII$sp
        at com.sample.WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:22)
        at com.sample.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/java8/JFunction2$mcIII$sp
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.java8.JFunction2$mcIII$sp
```

So what all needs to be done in this case?? I am using `spark 2.4.0` version and `scala 2.12.8 version` which is already installed on my windows.
Please help me since I am stuck in this since few days.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I only ever run on Linux. Not Windows.

Comment: Throws the same error in Linux as well

Comment: Can you use sbt for your build? If yes then sbt assembly plugin will take care of all dependencies to put in fat jar.

Comment: I used maven as the build tool that's why I posted pom.xml code

Comment: Really hard to do remote. I agree with other person. Sbt is way to go.

Comment: I never used sbt. I was able to do it few days back but now m seeing this error for the first time and couldn't find relevant solution for this on Google

Comment: Intellij being used?

Comment: No, i use eclipse ide

Comment: Can you just try it on my behalf using eclipse,linux atleast with the configuration which I mentioned here

Comment: I do not have that setup.

Comment: Anyone please help if possible

Answer (score 6):

looks like you are using 2.4.x with Scala 2.12. It might be compatibility issue.
*Spark documentation reference:- 
Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).*

Comment: Okay, will try it and let you know

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me after I change the scala version from 2.12.* to 2.11.*.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and solved it by changing the version of Scala I use during development to match the version Spark came with.

When I start Spark with `./spark-shell`, it says `Using Scala version 2.11.12`,
So I changed the Scala version in the build.sbt from `2.12.8` to `2.11.12` and everything worked.
I use Spark version `2.4.3`.

Comment: Your solution is not working. I am running it under Eclipse- Oracle Sun JDK 1.8 and Spark 3.4.0.
Using Scala version 2.12.17 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_361)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information. Even after setting scala version to 2.12.17 - it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct.

To add to them, don't forget to update the jar path in the `spark-submit` command when you change Scala versions. So if you're using sbt it's:

1. Update the Scala version to be compatible with Spark.
2. `sbt package`
3. Update the jar path in the spark-submit command. In my case it went from `target/scala-2.12/word-count-app_2.12-1.0.jar` to `target/scala-2.11/word-count-app_2.11-1.0.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using maven and this was a long time back :P